# XQuery to API Python String

Tags: python, regex, string, xquery, urllib

I am using Postman to convert Xqueries to Python strings for API. I now need to be able to convert the plain Xquery string to a API string in Python without using Postman.

For example here's the Xquery as a string

```
query_string = "xquery version '1.0-ml'; declare namespace html = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'; fn:count(fn:collection('foo'))"
```

is turned into the following string using Postman:

```
"xquery=xquery%20version%20%221.0-ml%22%3B%0Adeclare%20namespace%20html%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3B%0Afn%3Acount(fn%3Acollection('foo'))%0A%0A"
```

I now need to create the same string as above. If I try to use urrllib.parse.quote, it changes parenthesis and ' and makes the string:

```
urllib.parse.quote(query_string)

'xquery%20version%20%271.0-ml%27%3B%20declare%20namespace%20html%20%3D%20%27http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml%27%3B%20fn%3Acount%28fn%3Acollection%28%27foo%27%29%29'
```

Is there some other way to get the desired string outcome to match what Postman generates using plain Python?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what the desired outcome is from the way the question is phrased however if you don't want parenthesis encoded (unsure why you would want this as it's the correct behaviour) you can pass `safe` argument to `urllib.parse.quote`

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote(query_string, safe='()')
'xquery%20version%20%271.0-ml%27%3B%20declare%20namespace%20html%20%3D%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%27%3B%20fn%3Acount(fn%3Acollection(%27foo%27))'
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I also need to be able to keep the ' characters around foo.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the API I found this to work:

```
payload = 'xquery=' + urllib.parse.quote(query_string, safe="'()")
```